# Converting radians into degree

Tags: vb.net, math, trigonometry

I am currently making a small calculator for braggs law

```
lamda=2*d*SIN theta
```

Calculating wavelength from **d** and **theta**. in this input value of theta is in degrees. I have currently done this

```
 Dim l, d, t As Double
        d = 1.5
        t = 20         'input in degrees'
        l = 2 * d * Math.Sin(t)
        label1.text = l
```

The problem is the inbuilt **Math.Sin()** calculates sin as *radians*. Is there a function for calculating sin cos tan in  degrees for visual studio 2012. How can i convert radians to degrees.

Comment: How would you do it by hand?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math.

Comment: @DuckMaestro though not likely applicable for this OP, I find degree to radian conversion to be subtly a deep computing problem, especially with large values.  Suggest Google K.C. Ng's "Good to the Last Bit".

Comment: This quesiton has aboslutely nothing to do with Visual Studio, which is an IDE. Tag removed. Also, tags are not intended to be in the title.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the maths:)

```
rad=pi*deg/180
```

Answer (score 1):

If your theta `t` is in -360*N < t < +360*N (N < 1000), @Casimir et Hippolyte solution is fine.  Read no further unless interested.  But if you are using **large** degree values, you have stumbled into one of the minefields of computer programing.

The issue is that `t * pi` in a computer is *not* `t * pi` in the mathematical sense.  The `pi` of the computer is *nearly* pi.   Pi being an number with endless digits, is not exactly representable in computer.  Thus `t * about_pi` rounds off increasingly more digits as t becomes large.

The first thing you want to do with your multiplication is to call Math.Sin(t).  The first thing Math.Sin(t) does is to mathematically modulo by 2*pi.  A *good* sin() function will modulo by a very precise 2*pi and then work with the remainder.  Recall a huge  `t` in `t * about_pi` result in a significantly rounded value and Math.Sin(t) work with end up using that *rounded* value when it finally calculates sin().

But you have an advantage in that you can perform a modulo by `2*pi` far more accurately if you perform it before converting to radians as your modulo is 360 *exactly*.

The upshot of all this is

```
t = t Mod 360
```

then

```
rad = (2*pi)*t/360
```